# Matching timestamped GPS points to a path that has no timestamps

Tags: algorithm, gps, geospatial

I have two data sources available - one is timestamped GPS points, and another is a path fitted to roads, without timestamps (although points are ordered).

What I'm trying to do is combine the data sources into a fitted path that has interpolated timestamps based on the raw GPS points. Current attempts at an algorithm have not worked - it fails on edge cases such as sharp corners or paths that cross.

Is there an algorithm or some sort of math that I can use to do this? Something like minimising the sum of errors between GPS points and fitted paths, while keeping the points in order. I'm not sure how to translate this to a mathematical formula or algorithm however. I don't mind doing the work but need a pointer to what kind of math or algorithm I can use that will work well.

Answer (score 1):

As a building block, decide how to assess the goodness of fit (or cost) when k points are assigned to a single interval in the path. From the GPS timestamps, you know the relative order at which the k points were visited, so you could make your penalty for a single interval the length of a path within an interval that starts with the start of the interval, visits all of the k points in order, and ends with the end of the interval. You then want to assign all of the points to an interval to minimise the sum of the resulting costs - which is the length of the path that visits the start and end of every interval, and all of the available points, in an order given by the GPS timestamps and the assignments of points to intervals.

I think you can find the best assignment for this cost function using dynamic programming. Consider intervals in the path, one by one, in the order that they occur in the path. If there are just two intervals in the path, and there are k points, you can work out the best solution by just considering each of the k+1 possible splits that assign the j points with smallest GPS timestamp to the first interval and the other k-j points to the second interval, for j=0..k.

When there are more than two intervals in the path, consider them one by one, in ascending order, and build an array bestCost, where bestCost[i][j] is the best possible cost when you assign the first j points to the first i intervals. bestCost[1][j] is obvious as there are no decisions to make, and the previous paragraph explains bestCost[2][j]. For larger values of i, you can work out bestCost[i+1][j] from bestCost[i][j] for different values of j - consider each possible split of the first j GPS points between the i+1th interval and the first i intervals. Look up bestCost[i][s] to find the best cost for the s points you are considering assigning to the first i interval, and work out the distances travelled for the j-s points assigned to the i+1th interval. Sum the two for each possible split, and choose the lowest cost option.

Once you have worked out bestCost[i][j] for i = the number of intervals in the path and j = the total number of points you know the cost of the best answer, and you can track back to find the assignment of points to intervals that produces this. You can make this easier for yourself by keeping a little more book-keeping on the way forward than I have described here - typically you keep track of the value of s that provides the lowest cost answer for bestCost[i][j] in sChosen[i][j].